error: attach by pid 'xxxxx' failed -- attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process
I am facing problem with building app for simulator. After build complete this error appears:

and here are logs from console.app:

error suggest that there is some issue with memory space? But disc has 400GB empty space
What i have tried:

sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
Remove derived data
Turn off Debug Executable
Delete App and run again
Clean build folder from Xcode
Adding an environment variable IDEPreferLogStreaming with value YES


This error is likely related to permissions and security settings on macOS not disk space. "Operation not permitted" error usually occurs when the debugger doesn't have the necessary permissions to attach to the process.
You should try these solutions:
Try resetting all simulator settings:
xcrun simctl erase all

Check your Privacy & Security settings:

Go to System Preferences/Settings → Privacy & Security
Look for Developer Tools section
Ensure Xcode is allowed

Reset debugging permissions:
sudo security authorizationdb remove system.privilege.taskport
sudo security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport < /System/Library/Security/Privile­gedHelperTools/system.privilege.taskport.plist

Try running this command in Terminal:
csrutil status

If System Integrity Protection (SIP) is enabled, it might be interfering. However, I don't recommend disabling SIP unless absolutely necessary.
Check your signing settings in Xcode:

Select your project in the navigator
Select your target
Go to "Signing & Capabilities"
Ensure your team is selected and signing is valid

Try running Xcode as root (this is temporary for testing):
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch

If none of the above works, you should:
Restart Xcode
Restart your Mac
Reinstall Command Line Tools:
xcode-select --install

Try these solutions in order and if they still do not resolve the issue, then I would like to know which version of Xcode you’re using, version of macOS, and is this happening with all simulator devices or just specific ones?
